# I'm making a game in python

Tags: python

I want to detect any duplicate numbers given by the random number gen I coded in but don't know how.
This is what I have so far, I want to take the number given by the random number gen and find any duplicate numbers in it so I can give the player their multiplier for winning.

```
randomnum = random.randint(100, 999)
        print(randomnum)
```

I have tried a multitude of things I've found on the internet but of the ones I found that look promising I can't figure out how to take the number from my number gen and put it into the code that checks for duplicate numbers.
This is my most promising

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for n in numbers:
    if numbers.count(n) > 1:
        print("Repeated number:", n)
    if numbers.count(n) < 1:
        print("No repeated number:", n)
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to take the number given by my RNG and run it through this section of code, this is what I've tried.

```
randomnum = random.randint(100, 999)
print(randomnum)
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for n in numbers:
    if numbers.count(n) > 1:
        print("Repeated number:", n)
    if numbers.count(n) < 1:
        print("No repeated number:", n)
```

To be clear, I want a section of code that after taking the number given by my RNG (which will give me a 3 digit number, I need to see if any numbers from 1 to 9 are repeated) can see if any there are any duplicate numbers in it and then as a variable say if there were duplicates or not and if so if it was 2 or 3 numbers the same, not printed but something that will allow me to just give the player a multiplier back if there were 2 or more duplicates in the number. I am very new to python and don't know many terms surrounding the language, just the basics really, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "take number input"?  It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  You're generating one random number, but not using it.

Comment: What if `numbers.count(n) == 1`?

Comment: Agreed with Tim, what you need is hard to understand.
Please get one level above, and explain your main problem.

Comment: "I can't figure out how to take a number input" Have you tried [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: The question is probably about: "How can I check for duplicate *digits* in a given 3-digit number using Python?". If it so, please rewrite the question to be clear, by removing all the unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Are you maybe looking for `random.sample`? Something like

```
random.sample(range(100, 999), 10)
```

which gets you 10 numbers between 100 and 999 which are guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for here, but it sounds like you are generating random numbers and want to be able to detect when a generated number has been seen before. In this case, I would do something like this:

```
cache = set()
while <some condition>:
    randomnum = random.randint(100, 999)
    if randomnum in cache:
        print("Repeated number: ", randomnum)
    else:
        print("No repeated number: ", randomnum)
    cache.add(randomnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to generate n random integers in a given range and then determine whether any numbers are repeated. The code you found on the internet appears to be wrong in that it's looking for either `count(n) > 1` or `count(n) < 1` where the second condition should be `count(n) == 1` since it must be at least 1 if it's in the list. Then, of course you will have to edit the loop range to be your list `randomnum`. Try this:

```
import random

NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS = 10
RANDOM_NUMBER_RANGE = (10, 20)

randomnum = [random.randint(*RANDOM_NUMBER_RANGE) for i in range(NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS)]
print(randomnum)
print()

for n in randomnum:
    if randomnum.count(n) > 1:
        print("Repeated number:", n)
    if randomnum.count(n) == 1:
        print("No repeated number:", n)
```

Sample output:

```
[18, 16, 20, 11, 16, 16, 19, 19, 19, 19]

No repeated number: 18
Repeated number: 16
No repeated number: 20
No repeated number: 11
Repeated number: 16
Repeated number: 16
Repeated number: 19
Repeated number: 19
Repeated number: 19
Repeated number: 19
```

I made the range smaller so that some numbers would be repeated without making the list too long but you can adjust the values of `NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS` and `RANDOM_NUMBER_RANGE` as you wish.